# Attribute binding not working - Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

The `href` attribute scope binding is not working in `Ember.js`. I wanted it to be binded as `/fruits/1`. PFB the code.

**home.hbs**

```
<ul>
    {{#each fruits as |fruit|}}
        {{list-item href="/fruits/{{fruit.id}}" item=fruit onitemclick=(action "handleFruitsDetail")}}
    {{else}}
        <li>Loading!</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

`list-item` is a custom component where I am passing and binding `href`'s. PFB the code for it.

**list-item.hbs**

```
<li>
    <a href="{{href}}" onclick={{action "handleItemClick"}}>{{item.name}}</a>
</li>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`href="/fruits/{{fruit.id}}"` is not a valid syntax to give attributes to ember components. The correct syntax is:

```
{{list-item href=(concat "/fruits/" fruit.id) item=fruit onitemclick=(action "handleFruitsDetail")}}
```